# c# apicontroller gets called twice when it is called only once by getasync

Tags: c#, httpclient, asp.net-apicontroller

Hello I have encountered very interesting bug, and can't understand why is this happening. I call GetAllDocuments() method to api from my other project via GetAsync method of httpclient. But the problem is GetAllDocuments returns and then it gets called again! GetAsync returns result after GetAllDocuments returns twice.

Here is the calling method :

```
public static async Task<Document> GetAllDocuments()
    {
        try
        {

            var response =  _client.GetAsync("api/documents/GetAllDocuments").Result;
            response.Content.LoadIntoBufferAsync().Wait();
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            return await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Document>(new[] { new JsonMediaTypeFormatter() }); ;
            // Return the URI of the created resource.
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

ApiController method :

```
[HttpGet]
    public List<Document> GetAllDocuments()
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            _documentsRepository = DocumentsRepository.Instance;
            var result = _documentsRepository.GetDocuments();

            return result;
        }
    }
```

WebConfig :

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    private static HttpSelfHostServer _server;

    public static void Run(string port)
    {
        var config = new HttpSelfHostConfiguration($"http://localhost:{port}");//"http://localhost:8080");

        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            "API Default", "api/{controller}/{id}",
            new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            "newdocument", "api/documents/newdocument/{document}",new { document = RouteParameter.Optional });

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            "GetAllDocuments", "api/documents/GetAllDocuments/");

        config.MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue;;
        config.MaxBufferSize = int.MaxValue;
        _server = new HttpSelfHostServer(config);
        _server.OpenAsync();

    }

    public static void Stop()
    {
        _server?.CloseAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you block the first async call with .Result and await the other one? Don't Bock! Oh, and same goes for `Wait()`

Comment: @Crowcoder I think api still will be called twice. So how code should look like with your suggestion?

Comment: just use `await` exactly like you did with `ReadAsAsync` and remove the `.Result` and `Wait()`. If you ever do that outside of a console app you are doing it wrong.

Comment: @Crowcoder did what you suggested but the same thing :
    var response = await _client.GetAsync("api/documents/GetAllDocuments");
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                return await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Document>(new[] { new JsonMediaTypeFormatter() }); ;

Comment: I didn't say that was your solution, but you did need to fix it. Is that really your exact code for the controller? It should not compile because you are returning a Task but the signature is List<Document>.

Comment: Did you putting a break point in the static method and look at the stacktrace while paused there? See what is calling it on each hit. I wonder if you don't just have some mistake since the controller and method you are called are named identically.

Comment: @Crowcoder there is only one call in whole project. GetAllDocuments != DocumentController why you are saying they are identical?

Comment: You have an ApiController with a method name `GetAllDocuments`. You then have another method named `GetAllDocuments`. What I didn't notice until now, however, is that your controller calls something named `GetDocuments` (without the "...All..." in there). So, you are not even calling that first method you have shown. Whatever is wrong, we can't see it.

Comment: @Crowcoder GetDocuments has nothing to do with api cals since it retuns data from database, GetDocuments is not api method. There is no other method called GetAllDocuments httpmaproute just implements routing for api call of method.

Comment: This statement is confusing because you  show two methods named `GetAllDocuments`: "GetAllDocuments returns and then it gets called again! ". It is clear to you but it sure tripped me up. I still don't know which one gets called twice. Did you try my suggestion of  using a breakpoint and looking at the stacktrace?

Comment: @Crowcoder I think you should need more experience in web api, it looks like you don't understand.

Comment: I guess so, I only work in it every day. Mine never get called twice though.

Comment: @Crowcoder Those methods are in diferent projects one is service other is client. Yes they both have same names, but they are on diferent projects so it can't be a naming problem. Api controller method is called twice.

Comment: I'm not saying its a naming problem. I'm saying it is not clear which one is running twice. It would also help if you showed how you called the one that calls the API. It is important because async/await is very easy to misuse.